# Shortcode content not displaying on Home page

Tags: shortcode

Why don't shortcodes work when a post is view on Home page but they do when viewing single post.
You can see the issue [here](http://india.thefalljourney.com/).

There are suppose to be two element's above the image - generated by JW Player and a custom shortcode, and one shortcode below the image - generated by Lightbox Evolution plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Is the homepage pulling in the_excerpt() ?  If so you will have to add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

This will work if you are putting in manual excerpt. It shouldn't be stripping out the shortcode if you are using the_content() in your homepage template.

Comment: No, I used `content` not `the_content` nor `the_excerpt`. It's defined by this: `function content($limit) {
  $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
  if (count($content)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($content);
    $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
  } else {
    $content = implode(" ",$content);
  } 
  $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
  return $content;
}`
How do I modify your code and get it to work? I tried `content` in your code but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add another metabox for introductory text?  You can set that up easily with this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields-2/.

That way you can just use content and excerpt as they were intended...much less of a headache.

Comment: Because I use introductory text for FB and Twitter sharing. Two birds, one stone...

Comment: You could also just add a homepage excerpt box and when you pull it into the template you could use the do_shortcode() function. Example: echo do_shortcode($customfieldcontent);

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the function, you can use this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/) it can limit your excerpt, and you can also enable and disable the  the shortcodes.

Comment: So you think there's no way around it if I use `content`? I use it because I use `the_excerpt` on my single post to display "introductory" text for a post.